# How to make a moving circle delete on impact with another circle in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
canvas =Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000, bg= '#2B2B2B')
canvas.pack()

#id1 white
x = 400
y = 400
r = 50

#rc2 orange
f = 100
d = 400
r2 =100



id1 = canvas.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, outline='white')


id2 = canvas.create_oval(f - r2, d - r2, f + r2, d + r2, outline='#CC7832')



def move_circle():
    for k in range(31):


        time.sleep(0.025)

        canvas.move(id2, 5, 0)
        canvas.update()

def get_coords(id_num):

    pos = canvas.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2

    print(x, y)
    return x, y


from math import sqrt


def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    print("distance", x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

def delete_circle():   #12
    if distance(id1, id2) < (r+r2):
        canvas.delete(id2)

move_circle()
delete_circle()
root.mainloop()
```

'''Hi Guys, I am trying to get circle id2 to delete when it hits id1. At the moment this only works if I have my range
set to between 31-89 in the move circle function. I understand that the reason this is the case is because the delete function only executes when the move circle function has completed it's loop. I think the solution is to somehow get the delete function to have access to the coordinate changes as they occur during the loop. However I have hit a wall to say the least on trying to do this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Have you tried calling delete circle from in the move circle for loop (and probably breaking out of the loop if the circle i deleted)

Comment: Just to clarify I am trying to get delete_circle() to work in the range after 31-39 i.e in the range 100 for example. Many thanks.

Comment: sorry Jeremy, just saw your comment, will have a look at your suggestion,

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I have added the delete circle function to the move function as you suggested, but it either causes the program to crash or the circle id2 bounces back? The error messages are:    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Sorry about that. I am glad you got a better idea.

Comment: No worries Jeremy, thanks for taking the time anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You just need find_overlapping method.

Basic example :

```
id1 = canvas.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, outline='white')
id2 = canvas.create_oval(f - r2, d - r2, f + r2, d + r2, outline='#CC7832')

id1_coords = canvas.coords(id1)

def move_circle(x, y):
    canvas.move(id2, x, y)
    if id2 not in canvas.find_overlapping(*id1_coords) :
        canvas.after(100, move_circle, x, y)
    else :
        canvas.delete(id2)

move_circle(5, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi brodeur, thanks for getting back to me. Your code seem to be working, thanks a million! I have not come across the find_overlapping method before. Thanks again, this was driving me crazy! Cheers.

Comment: Hi brodeur, the circle seems to move a bit slower and a bit more jumpy than in my original loop, do you know if there is a reason for this? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's slow and jerky because I have setted 100 to first argument in the after method, 100 is a delay in millisecond, if you want 0.025 as in your code, use 25 instead or another value :)

Comment: Thanks brodeur, will do that. Thanks again!!